# Execute an external program from Python script

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, subprocess, executable, python-os

I need to run an external program from my Python script.
I can start applications like Notepad but I have a problem with one game. It starts as configured in windowed mode when I execute it from WinExlorer or Command Prompt. But when I try to run it from my script by

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(r'G:\Python\knight-mare\kmare_gold_win32\Kmare.exe')
```

**Edit:** Just figured out that `subprocess.run` does not fit me because it waits for the process to finish.

```
import os
os.system(r'G:\Python\knight-mare\kmare_gold_win32\Kmare.exe')
import win32api
win32api.WinExec(r'G:\Python\knight-mare\kmare_gold_win32\Kmare.exe')
```

I have the same result: it starts in a full-screen mode, resolution changes and there is only a black screen.

P.S. while running from the explorer it appears in the Task Manager as:

> NERLASKA Engine (32bit) - Knightmare Remake ...

while from the script:

> NERLASKA Engine (32bit) - nltkENGINE

Any advice?

**P.P.S. I had found a way around it by creating a Win shortcut to my execution file and then running it by `os.startfile(r'G:\KmareShortcut.lnk')` but I still want to understand the roots of this behavior**

Comment: Have you set up your system to launch your Python interpreter under a different user account?

Comment: no, they are running from the same

Comment: Does your shortcut contain a non-empty value for *"Start in"*? In that case you can try to set the current directory when launching the executable, and see if that works. This would be a good time to drop the use of [WinExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winexec), which is really a left-over of 16-bit Windows (that's Windows 1, 2, and 3). [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) allows you to set the initial directory.